# The bottom of page cannot display in WKWebView

Tags: scroll, wkwebview

A long web page is rendered in a WKWebView, but a small part of the page on the bottom cannot display even scrolling the page to the bottom.

It seems that the bottom of the page is out of the screen because I can see it when I pull the page up and not releasing my finger.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am coming to answer my own question as I have found out the reason that made this issue.

I don't have enough knowledge about Objective-C, so maybe there will be some small mistakes when I describing my answer.

Firstly, there is a default margin at the top of the `WKWebView` if the property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` was set to `true`, and maybe there is a bug of XCode 8.3 (everything was going well when I compiled my code with XCode 8.0), the margin occupied a real part of web page, so the web page can not scroll to its bottom even though I set it to a small size. So set the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `false` will remove the margin of `WKWebView`; This is the documentation of this property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin

Then, set the height of `WKWebView` by the calculation result of that the height of viewport minus the height of the status bar and minus the height of navigation bar.

Pasting my code here:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, statusBarHeight + navBarHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - statusBarHeight - navBarHeight )];
```